# PostgreSQL constraint details

Tags: postgresql

How do I get details for a given constraint name in PostgreSQL?  I have the following error message, and I am trying to determine which table and columns the constraint is referring to:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"events_pkey\"\n Detail: Key (id)=(258) already exists."
```

Comment: `select * from information_schema.constraint_column_usage where constraint_name = 'events_pkey'`

Answer (score 0):

It says in the message that the primary key column `id` uniqueness is violated. You are trying to insert the row with id=258, but it already exists.

Comment: I know that. The problem is, the PK for that table is a sequence. How can I violate a PK constraint for a column that is serial? I was hoping for some more information from the data dictionary to clue me into what is happening.

Comment: @DooDah: there are two possible reasons: 1) your sequence is out of sync. 2) you are (or have been) inserting values manually.

Comment: Thanks. That is more or less what I thought. I am not inserting values manually. Not sure how a sequence can get out of sync. I had just restored the database when this happened. Are the sequences stored inside the database I restored, or, in the data dictionary somewhere?

Comment: Normally in a restore script the sequences are reset to the highest value that has just been imported. This could have failed (permissions, wrong schema, ...)